# How to hide the application during the runtime?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

How to hide the application during the runtime. During the run time when i click the button , i need to perform the action application will close and then hide the application in phone. How to achieve this, even jailbroken iOS is not a problem. How to do.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Create another application, open it with a custom url, make sure it always crashes =D

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'hide'?

Comment: @creker "When i login to the application that application view was closed and application also need not show to iPhone user this application, but application want run on background."

Answer (score 0):

add these line to you plist but it will hide your app forever on frist run

SBAppTags
    hidden